# How to add a loader for slow network in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-post

I've created a subscription page and on submitting the page doesn't redirect like it is supposed to for people with slow network. Is there a way I can put a loader on the submit button to fix that because it ruins the user experience a little. This is how my submit function looks like.

```
const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = {
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        contact_number: phone,
        organization: organization,
        designation: designation,
      },
    };

    // Send mailchimp data to lambda
    body = {
      data: {
        ...body.data,
        mailchimp: {
          email_address: email,
          status: newsletter ? "subscribed" : "unsubscribed",
          merge_fields: {
            FNAME: name,
            PHONE: phone,
            MMERGE6: organization,
            JOBTYPE: designation,
            SIGNUPSOUR: Book.fields.contentpieceId,
          },
        },
      },
    };
    setShowModal(false);
    if (window) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("@landing:sub-emai", email);
    }

    console.log(body);

    if (!isDanger) {
      axios
        .post(
          "{API}/prod/api",
          body
        )
        .then((resp) => {
          if (resp.status === 200) {
            window.location.href = `/case-study/${eBook.fields.redirectUrl}`;
          } else {
            setError(true);
          }
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: maintain a state variable to detect if the request is in progress or not, then based on that state variable add a loading as you need.

Comment: How can I detect if the request is in progress or not?

Comment: add a state variable at the top `(requestIsInProgress: false)`, then update it just before the axio call `(requestIsInProgress: true)`,, and again update it after completing the request (inside .then() callback) `(requestIsInProgress: false)`,

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't understand the inner working behind this, how does adding a state solve the problem

Comment: So you have a state variable which can detect whether the request is in progress or not, then based on the state variable you can show a loader in the html

Comment: And if I don't show a loader will the submit request still work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provide an example based on your data that might help you. I created state `loading` with default value false. While you are fetching data you set `loading` to true, after it finished set `loading` to false. If `loading` sets to true it shows spinner to you.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default function MyComponent() {
    const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true) // data is fetching

        // do your job with axios

        axios.post("{API}/prod/api", "body")
            .then((resp) => {
                if (resp.status === 200) {
                    window.location.href = `/case-study/blw`;
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(e))
            .finally(function () {
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {loading && < Spinner/>}
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```